# Drupal - how to set active trail when using book?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-theming

I'm creating a sub theme for Omega and am using a book for hierarchical navigation.  The problem I have is that when I click on a link that is in the third level of navigation, the active trail isn't set.  E.g. when I go to the page called 'what to do when things go wrong', the first level nav isn't highlighted and the second level nav isn't shown:

[image]

It should look like the following:

[image: Primary Navigation]

I've created the following book:

[image: Book]

My book outline for the third-level page looks like this:

[image]

It feels like I've done everything I need to set the active trail but it's not working.  How can I set the active trail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I managed this in the end, was to create a new book at second level.  Then use context module to apply the active menu trail.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a drupal version older than 7.9, use the following code:

```
menu_tree_set_path('main-menu', 'path');
```

Comment: I'm on version 7.7, unfortunately and menu_set_tree_path is available from 7.9 onward.

Comment: Looks like I can define it myself as shown in the following comment: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_tree_set_path/7#comment-23598  I'll give it a go and see how I get on